# How to limit a regex capturing group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't get how I can limit a capturing group.

If I have a regex like this:

```
/^(\w{2,}\s\w{2,}){4,15}$/
```

I would think that this would capture any string with:

- Exact two words,
- With each word least 2 characters long,
- And whole string no longer than 15 characters.

But the limiting of my capturing groups doesn't work. Can I limit capturing groups at all?

PS. I am using JavaScript to test the regexes in my examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This lookahead based regex should work for you:

```
/^(?=.{4,15}$)\w{2,}\s\w{2,}$/
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sN2zH5)

Your regex: `^(\w{2,}\s\w{2,}){4,15}$` basically means there should be between 4 to 15 instances of a string containing *2 words with at least 2 characters separated by a space*

Comment: @Nano The `{4,15}` is essentially saying that the captured group can occur between 4 and fifteen times.  You want to put a limit on the actual count of characters.

Comment: @Nano: See comment from ExplosionPills and my edited answer for that.

Comment: *facepalm* ... I am so embarrassed :S ... now that you mention it ... Thanks! :D

Comment: For this specific case you can use `(?!.{16})` too

Comment: ...or perhaps more efficient: `^\w{2}(?!.{14})\w*\s\w{2,}$`

Comment: Yes that appears more interesting regex.