# Regex pattern to validate string with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I'm trying to write a regex pattern that validates a string by meeting a number of requirements but I believe I have to apply conditions to a capture group which I don't fully understand even after looking at articles.

I'm looking to loosely confirm that a string has a valid file type at the end of it e.g. `filename.png`.

Using a string similar to above I would like to:

- match the substring after the final full stop in the string
- check that this substring is only comprised of letters and numbers
- check that it is less than or equal to 5 characters long

I've found this post, [How to limit a regex capturing group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210875/how-to-limit-a-regex-capturing-group), but don't know how I'd go about combining it into my pattern.

Currently I have `/\.[^.]*(a-zA-Z0-9)*$/g` which works for `file.name.png` but doesn't meet any of the other conditions and I don't know where I'd position `{0,5}`.

How would I go about isolating the substring and applying the second two conditions to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take

```
/\.[a-z0-9]{0,5}$/i
```

which looks for

- a dot
- up to five letters or digits
- end of the string
- case insensitive search

Answer (score 1):

How about `/\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,5}$/`

this will match a literal `.` followed by up to 5 letters or digits.

Comment: are you sure, that it works without a number in the first part of the quantifier. the [standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-regular-expressions-patterns) does not mention it. please have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/r1vXqC/1), too.

Comment: @NinaScholz quite correct, PCRE do support this but JS doesn't, oops. Updated answer!